# JSON syntax Content - type: application / json

Tags: json

I'm having trouble with a JSON file that i created, and was told to add to it a header as this: Content - type: application / json .
The problem is that it didn't work for me and i've tried many syntax:

```
Content - type: application / json
[
{"name":"    ","image":"    " },
{"name":"    ","image":"      "},
{"name":"     ","image":"     "}
]
```

and this

```
[
Content - type: application / json
{"name":"    ","image":"    " },
{"name":"    ","image":"      "},
{"name":"     ","image":"     "}
]
```

this is my first time dealing with JSON so bear with me
Thank you.

Comment: What language are you using with your JSON file?

Comment: Send the *[HTTP `Content-Type` header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields)* - how this is done will depend based on what *returns* the JSON from the web server. Don't add the text literally 'to' the JSON as [the JSON](http://json.org/) will be [invalid](http://jsonlint.com/) if it contains that "content - type" garbage.

Comment: I'm having a javascript file that is dealing with the JSON and an html that is calling the javascript file.
do i put the content type in the index.html as such ?
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta Content-type: application/json>    
    </head>

Comment: i've also tried this in the index.html <?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
?> did not work

Comment: Any help ?  I've done my research but nothing that i've tried worked